# Running a buildscript.xml file from jenkins

Tags: windows, ant, jenkins, build

I am new to Jenkins CI and i am trying to run my buildscript.xml file from jenkis in windows OS,
can someone help me how do i do it correctly? Alternatively i have a build.bat batch file too, if i execute it in command prompt like ">build.bat trunk head"
it invokes build script and starts the build.
how can i accomplish the same in jenkins?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: my buidscript.xml file has ant tasks, which will take care of the build.

Comment: it works fine if i use command prompt to execute the script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a new **Freestyle job**
- Select your **Source Code** system (svn, git, etc)
- Specify which repo to check out from, and into which folder, for example `my_co`
- The checkout will be available in what's known as *workspace*, and you can reference it's absolute location with `%WORKSPACE%\my_co` anywhere in the build
- Create **Invoke Ant** build step, and specify location of your `buildscript.xml`, relative to `%WORKSPACE%`, and optional which targets to execute.
  **OR**
- Create **Execute Windows Batch Command** build step, and call your batch file, again the location is relative to `%WORKSPACE%`

Comment: Is there a way that will deploy the files in to server automatically once the build is successful?

Comment: Depends on server, OS, and type of files you are trying to deploy... For something common, like a `.war` file to Tomcat, there are plugins. But I always find them lacking, and end up writing my own deployment scripts

Comment: i wrote a custom ant task to do the same and added it as additional build step. working fine so for. Thanks for the replys.